# Force logout using signalr in ASP.net core

Tags: asp.net-core-2.1, signalr-hub, asp.net-core-signalr

I have an ASP.Net core (version 2.1) web application in which i need to force logout the user automatically if same user  logged in another browser(session) using signalr hub.

I have override Onconnected event in server to get the user list and started the connection hub from client. I am not getting the logged-in user details from Hub Context

```
        public override Task OnConnectedAsync()
        {
            string userName = Context.User.Identity.Name;
            string connectionId = Context.ConnectionId;

            if (CurrentSessionUsers != null && !(CurrentSessionUsers.Exists(x => x.ConnectionId == Context.ConnectionId)))
            {

                CurrentSessionUsers.Add(new CurrentUserSession()
                {
                    UserEmail = Context.User.Claims.Count() > 0 ? Context.User.FindFirst(ClaimIdentifiers.Email.ToString()).Value.ToString() : string.Empty,
                    ConnectionId = Context.ConnectionId,
                    RequestTime = DateTime.Now
                });
            }

            return base.OnConnectedAsync();
        }
```

Code from client:

```
            var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder().withUrl("/signalrhub").build();
            connection.serverTimeoutInMilliseconds = 1000000;
            connection.start().then(function () {

            }).catch(function (err) {
                var errorc = console.error(err.toString());
                return errorc;
            });
```

My problem is i'm not getting the user details in Context and whether the procedure is right or not.

Answer (score 1):

In my opinion, if you check the user based its connection id, it will be OK. But if user start a new browser tab to start a new session. This will also created a new connection id.

According to your logic, this will also make the user logout.

If your requirement is let the user only login in just one tab even if user is in the same browser. This will work well.

Besides, this will also make the user re-login if the user close all the tabs and re-call the hub method.

Comment: Thanks for your clarification. @BrandoZhang.  So i can use "session Id" instead of connection Id to achieve my requirement?

Comment: And my another query is, the Context.User.Identity.Name always return null even the user logged in. Whether i missed anything ?

Comment: Could you please tell me how you login the user? By using asp.net core default identity?